# Как добавить элемент массива через обновления состояния компонента?

Tags: reactjs

index.js

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import {render} from 'react-dom';
import ItemsList from "../src/components/App"



const propsValues = {
  title: "Список смартфонов",
  items: [
          "HTC U Ultra", 
          "iPhone 7", 
          "Google Pixel", 
          "Hawei P9", 
          "Meizu Pro 6",
          "Asus Zenfone 3"
  ]
};


render(<ItemsList data={propsValues} />, document.getElementById('root'));
```

app.js

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';

class Item extends React.Component {
  render() {
      return <li>{this.props.name}</li>;
  }
}

class ItemsList extends React.Component {
  constructor(props){
      super(props);
      this.state = { items: this.props.data.items};
  }

  render() {
      return(
          <div>         
              <h2>{this.props.data.title}</h2>
              <ul>
                  {
                      this.state.items.map(function(item){
                          return <Item key={item} name={item} />
                      })
                  }
              </ul>
              <button onclick={this.appArr}>ok</button>
          </div>);
  }

}

 export default ItemsList;
```

Пытаюсь добавить новый массив a через через setState, но не работает

```
function appArr() {
    let a = [1];
    this.setState(
    {
        items: [...a, this.props.data.items]
    }
)
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. В реакте регистр имеет значение. Ваш пример не работает, потому что у вас на кнопке стоит `onclick` вместо `onClick`.
2. После исправления пример работает, но не так как надо))). Исправил функцию `appArr`

```js
const propsValues = {
  title: "Список смартфонов",
  items: [
          "HTC U Ultra", 
          "iPhone 7", 
          "Google Pixel", 
          "Hawei P9", 
          "Meizu Pro 6",
          "Asus Zenfone 3"
  ]
};

class Item extends React.Component {
  render() {
      return <li>{this.props.name}</li>;
  }
}

class ItemsList extends React.Component {
  constructor(props){
      super(props);
      this.state = { items: this.props.data.items};
  }

  render() {
      return(
          <div>         
              <h2>{this.props.data.title}</h2>
              <ul>
                  {
                      this.state.items.map(function(item){
                          return <Item key={item} name={item} />
                      })
                  }
              </ul>
              <button onClick={this.appArr}>ok</button>
          </div>);
  }
  
  appArr = () => {
    let items = this.state.items;
    items.push('a');
    this.setState({
        items: items
    });
  }
}

ReactDOM.render(<ItemsList data={propsValues} />, document.getElementById('root'));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.6.3/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.6.3/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
<div id="root"></div>
```